# iOS events to load data from server

Tags: ios, event-handling

In iOS Mail for example, the app **always** seems to refresh when the screen is shown, regardless of how often I open and close it.

I'm trying to duplicate the functionality via `viewWillAppear`. But one thing I noticed during testing is that `viewWillAppear` is not always invoked when the app is run, but it's always invoked when going back from a sub-view. So when it is opened, it may or may not refresh, which can be annoying.

Is there another event and/or object I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a in depth look at the below image showing the app life cycle.

[image: Application lifecycle]

Answer (score 1):

You should have a method `applicationWillEnterForeground:` in your AppDelegate. This method is called each time the app comes back to the foreground

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}
```